# Inquiry about the shading technique used in this artwork

Tags: shaders, compositing-nodes, shader-nodes, toon-shading

[image: reference]

Can someone help me with this? How to achieve this look in Blender.
Original Project - https://www.behance.net/gallery/56244769/Vampires

Comment: What have you achieve so far ? Where are you stuck ? There are *tons* of shaders and techniques in your example. Keywords to help you : black&white, low key lighting, clipped blacks, dithering.